# javascript update next/previous input field value

Tags: javascript

I have a table that for each record has an input field with a minus and plus button either side of it. I am trying to get it so that when the user click on the plus button it increases the input field's value by one and vice-versa for the minus button.

I generate my table records for JavaScript:

```js
  + "<td class=\"text-center\">"
  +   "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\"value=\"" + b.id +  "\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"minus\" data-card-type=\"nonfoil\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/minus.png\"></span>"
  +   "<input type=\"number\" class=\"page-input-inventory\" maxlength=\"5\" autocomplete=\"off\" tabindex=\"1\" value=\"" + b.n2 + "\">"
  +   "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\"value=\"" + b.id +  "\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"plus\" data-card-type=\"nonfoil\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/plus.png\"></span>"
  + "</td>"
```

updateCard:

```js
function updateCard(e) {
  if (e.getAttribute('data-type') == 'minus'){
    var value = parseInt($(this).next().value);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    $(this).next().value = value;
  } else if (e.getAttribute('data-type') == 'plus'){
    var value = parseInt($(this).previous().value);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    $(this).previous().value = value;
  }
};
```

I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).previous is not a function
    at updateCard (inventory.js:42)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: Try `prev()` instead

Comment: This removes the error above, thank you, but the input field still doesn't change expected

Comment: Update your question with a image of front end so that I can easily understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistakes:

1. you should use `e` instead of `this`. `this` refers to the jquery object.
2. it is `val` not `value`.
3. `val()` is a method not a property.

this works:

```
function updateCard(e) {
  if (e.getAttribute('data-type') == 'minus'){
    var value = parseInt($(e).next().val());
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    $(e).next().val(value);
  } else if (e.getAttribute('data-type') == 'plus'){
    var value = parseInt($(e).prev().val());
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    $(e).prev().val(value);
  }
};
```

finaly. you can omit `parseInt`. the input is already of type `number`.